# Accept non negative float values in apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am creating an xlsx file using apache POI in java. I want a cell to have only non negative floating values with 2 decimal places at most. I am using createNumericConstraint for this, although in the file, it doesn't accept 0 as a value. (Find the code below). 
And I have no idea how to implement the 2 decimal places constraint on this as of yet.

Already got the answer for 2 decimal places. What I am stuck at is that it doesn't accept 0 as a value.

```
    DataValidationHelper helper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
    DataValidationConstraint constraint;
    DataValidation validation;
    constraint = helper.createNumericConstraint(XSSFDataValidationConstraint.ValidationType.DECIMAL,
            XSSFDataValidationConstraint.OperatorType.BETWEEN,
            String.valueOf(0),
            String.valueOf(Float.MAX_VALUE));

    CellRangeAddressList cellRangeAddressList = new CellRangeAddressList();

    cellRangeAddressList.addCellRangeAddress(new CellRangeAddress(1, lastRowIndex, columns.get(SELLING_PRICE.getName()), columns.get(SELLING_PRICE.getName())));
    cellRangeAddressList.addCellRangeAddress(new CellRangeAddress(1, lastRowIndex, columns.get(MRP.getName()), columns.get(MRP.getName())));

    validation = helper.createValidation(constraint, cellRangeAddressList);
    validation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
    validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
    sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format all numbers using this line:

```
style.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("0.00"));
```

The `0` does show up as required format every time. So some examples:

- 0   ->   0.00
- 1   ->   1.00
- 1.5 ->   1.50
- 99   ->  99.00
- 137.7 -> 137.70

And last but not least the validation need to be changed from `String.valueOf(0)` to `0.00f` so the format and correct datatype (`float`) is used. Otherwise there can be conversation/type-errors afterwards.

Comment: Okay, This handles the 2 decimal places. But what about rejecting negative values?

Comment: Your validation is looking fine to me. It´s getting created, defined and added to the sheet with a rangelist. I just would guess that the rangelist is not correct.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but I have checked, rangelist is fine. This constraint is applied on the correct cells, It's just that it is not accepting 0 as a value. That's why I am confused with this.

Comment: and if you change it to `String.valueOf(0.00f)`? It should be the same but maybe there is a convertation issue for min-values. Just give it a try.

Comment: HOLY CRAP, You're right. That fixed it.  Update this in your original answer. I'd mark it as the answer.

Comment: I realy hate such easy type errors. Why can´t int 0 be same like 0.0f when floating numbers are used. Other languages can handle it correct. But nice if it´s working now.